# React - Embedded website and detect link clicked

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to create a small react app in typescript that does the following :

- Embedding a website let's say Hackernews (https://news.ycombinator.com/)
- From there I want to detect when a user tap a link. Ideally with a callback that let me know what url the user tried to access to
- Lastly is it possible to prevent the redirection from said Link, if for instance the link they tapped doesn't belong to the initial domain in this case : `news.ycombinator`

I am using this project as a way to learn: react/typescript/web dev

- First of all is it possible to achieve
- Maybe detecting link tap from the embedded could be a security issues and therefor is not technically possible

Cheers

Comment: I think first you should set a class name for the link, and then add a event listener. When the user clicks on the click, save a message to your database, and retrieve it when necessary. Every time the user clicks on the link it will be saved to the db and you can retrieve it when needed.

Comment: I want the link callback from the embedded website. I imagine an Iframe (unless better there is better?) will be used to display it. So I won't have control over any properties on the links.